# Problems with creating lotto ticket

Tags: c++

I have to create a program that looks like the printout of a lotto ticket.
Yet I can't seem to get the "mega" number in the right place. We have to generate 5 random numbers between 1 and 56, then one more number between 1 and 44 (the mega number). So its supposed to look like this:
[image]

Yet for some reason the mega number always prints before the 5 random numbers generated between 1 and 56.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include "cs110a2.h"
using namespace std;

void fillup(int x[], int n, int from, int to)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        x[i] = RAND(from,to);
    }

    cout <<" ";
    cout << RAND(1,44); 
}

int bubble_sort(int x[], int n)   
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
    {
        int temp;

        for(int j=i+1; j<n ; j++)
        {
            if(x[i] > x[j])
            {
                temp = x[i];
                x[i] = x[j];
                x[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return(0);        //What! why?
}


void print(int x[], int n)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << x[i] <<" ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    srand(time(NULL)); 

    cout <<"                  Mega" << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < atoi(argv[1]); i++)
    {
        int lotto[5];

        fillup(lotto,5,1,56);                    

        bubble_sort(lotto,5);

        print(lotto,5);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: For those of us who don't know what a lotto ticket is (yes, such people do exist) could you offer some explanation and context? Also, always prefer text to a screenshot - it can be searched for, occupies less space, and can be cut and pasted. Also, if you are using C++ for such a question (a) it's off topic here (b) it's probably the wrong tool. You're better off using Python, Perl, or R (or something similar).

Comment: @FaheemMitha: "Lotto ticket" is a pretty generic English phrase. I think it's beyond the threshold at which a Google search is expected if you aren't familiar with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the last two lines from the fillup function to the end of the print function.
 As it is now, you're printing the mega after GENERATING the numbers, not after printing them.

Answer (score -1):

string formatting using the \t ( tab ) to place  where it needs to be.

Comment: That just ends up tabing everything over.

Comment: focus on this line cout <<"                  Mega" << endl;